# Fabric(twitter api) setup issue. Using swift

Tags: swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

Hi I am using the Twitter API for the first time and have little experience with APIs in general. I installed the [fabric app](https://get.fabric.io/) and am following the documentation to integrate twitter using swift.

When I build my app and install the twitter option on fabric, it asks me to run my code.

When I do that I get a 'Signal SIGABRT' error on the line `Fabric.with([Twitter()])` in the `AppDelegate.swift` file.
Before this I had added the import TwitterKit line to the `AppDelegate`.

I also tried to add these lines following the API documentation:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey("your_key", consumerSecret: "your_secret")
Fabric.with([Twitter.sharedInstance()])
```

and then the error comes in the `Twitter.sharedInstance()` line.
I am adding these lines in the func Application method.

From the language I use, it is very evident that I am a newbie to programming and really need good help smiley

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem, I did the following:

1. Open XCode Target
2. Go to the "Build phases" tab
3. Click the "Copy bundle resources" section
4. Click the add button
5. Add TwitterKitResurce.bundle